# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc Aborted

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting a `bad_alloc` exception in my program.

These are the constraints:

- 1 <= T <= 10
- The length of each string is at most 100000 and contains only lower case characters.

With those constraints, I am unable to figure out why my program is getting `bad_alloc`.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class SuffixArray {
    std::vector<std::string> suffixes;
    size_t N;
public:
    SuffixArray(std::string& s) {
        N = s.length();
        suffixes.resize(N);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
            suffixes[i] = s.substr(i);
        std::sort(suffixes.begin() , suffixes.end());
    }
    ~SuffixArray() {
    }
    size_t lcp(std::string& s, std::string& t) {
        size_t N = std::min(s.length(), t.length());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (s[i] != t[i]) 
                return i;
        return N;
    }    
};

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    std::vector<size_t> results;

    for ( int i = 0; i < T; i++) { 
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;
        SuffixArray sa(str);
        size_t sol = 0;

        for ( std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
            std::string target = std::string(it, str.end());
            sol += sa.lcp(str, target);            
        }
        results.push_back(sol);
    }
    for ( std::vector<size_t>::iterator it = results.begin(); it != results.end(); ++it) 
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    results.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input causes this exception and where does it occur?

Comment: Do You mean " I am unable to figure out why my program is getting bad_alloc"?

Comment: @David Brown, unfortunately I do not know for what input this is causing, This I am trying for some programming contest. I made local file with 100000 characters per line and 10 lines and it is working fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because what you do here:

```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        suffixes[i] = s.substr(i);
```

is: Create `N` sub strings of lengths 0, 1, 2, ..., N
The total amount of memory these are going to consume is: `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N` bytes. Having good old Gauss at your hand you will find that the sum of the first `N` numbers is: `N * (N + 1) / 2`

Now if you set N = 100,000 this results in about 5GB of memory consumption - which is larger than the max. 2GB address space your program usually has unless you run it on a 64bit system.

**Edit**: I don't know what the problem is you are trying to solve however your implementation seems strange:

You never ever use the computed suffixes: The only function of `SuffixArray` you are using is `lcp` which makes no reference to the stored `suffixes` vector. So what you need them for in the first place?

Comment: but I need this for my suffix array, any clue on how to fix this.

Comment: @Avinash Perhaps the goal of the contest was for you to find some better representation.  I can think of two right off; the most obvious is not to create substrings, simply store ranges (a pair of positions) into the original string.  But I suspect that you need even less; given the data, `suffixes` could be a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @james Kanze, how can i have vector<int>, I have to store strings right !!! or I am missing something.

Comment: @Avinash - I guess the idea is not to copy all the substrings, but  only store the data once and keep track of where they are.

Comment: @Avinash You have one string to start with; all of the strings you put in the vector are determined by a single offset into the original string.  So keep the original string somewhere, and use the offset.  (More generally, when parsing or processing string data, I've found it very effective to use pairs of iterators instead of strings.  All of the standard algorithms operate on pairs of iterators, so there's no need to keep hundreds of copies of the characters.)